# Running Nightwatch test inside docker - Selenium server doesn't start

Tags: selenium, jenkins, docker, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to integrate my e2e test in our CI pipeline.
We are using Jenkins as CI and we build a docker image and all the tests are running from the docker.

When trying to run the e2e tests I receive an error stating: "Connection refused! Is selenium server started?"

After building the image and installing all the npm packages I use this command in the Jenkins file:

```
run_in_stage('End2End test', {
    image.inside("-u root") {
        sh '''
            npm run build:dev
            http-server ./dist -p 3001 -s &
            xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1600x1200x24" npm run test:e2e:smoke
        '''
    }
})
```

In the docker file I set up Chrome with xvfb.

```
  RUN \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y xvfb google-chrome-stable
```

This is how I set up the selenium in the nightwatch.conf.js file:

```
const seleniumServer = require('selenium-server-standalone-jar');
const chromeDriver = require('chromedriver');

selenium: {
  start_process: true,
  server_path: seleniumServer.path,
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 4444,
  cli_args: {
    'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromeDriver.path
  }
},
```

Comment: Is selenium actually running on your container ?

Comment: @AlexandreFILLATRE I suppose not, how can I run it?

Comment: I would suggest t take a look at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium. Run Selenium in another container, and configure your own container to connect with it. If you use Docker > 1.10, then use the network configuration, else use the `--link` option

Comment: You can also use Zalenium, start with `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dosel/t/i/p | bash -s start` then right after  `docker run --net=container:zalenium your_test_image` so by providing `--net=container:zalenium` you tell the container to run on the same network than the selenium server already provided for you. Is the easiest setup and works locally or in Jenkins.